# How to do a ManyToMany relationship insert

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am studying spring boot data using this API [SWAPI](https://swapi.dev/), I did almost things but now I dont know how to map the relationship about two lists, above you can see my code and entities.

Entity Film

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Film extends Persistent<Long> {

    private String title;

    @JsonProperty(value = "episode_id")
    private int episodeId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "opening_crawl")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CLOB")
    private String openingCrawl;

    private String director;

    private String producer;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalDateConverter.class)
    @JsonProperty(value = "release_date")
    private LocalDate releaseDate;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = ApiURLToEntitiesConverter.class)
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "films")
    private List<Person> characters;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime edited;

    private String url;
}
```

Entity Person

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Person extends Persistent<Long> {

    private String name;

    private String height;

    private String mass;

    @JsonProperty(value = "hair_color")
    private String hairColor;

    @JsonProperty(value = "skin_color")
    private String skinColor;

    @JsonProperty(value = "eye_color")
    private String eyeColor;

    @JsonProperty(value = "birth_year")
    private String birthYear;

    private String gender;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = ApiURLToEntityConverter.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "planet_id", foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name = "none"))
    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    private Planet homeworld;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = ApiURLToEntitiesConverter.class)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "film_person",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "film_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true))
    private List<Film> films;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToLocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    private LocalDateTime edited;

    private String url;
}
```

I am trying to use the spring jpa method to saveAll

```
@Override
public List<T> insertAll(List<T> entities) {

    for (Persistent entity : entities) {

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Persistent>> violations = validator.validate(entity);

        if (violations != null && !violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }

    return repository.saveAll(entities);
}
```

Converter Method

```
    @Override
    public List convert(List<String> s) {

        if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        List objetos = new LinkedList();

        for (String url : s) {

            if (url.contains("people")) {
                objetos.add(Util.getPerson(url));
            }

            if (url.contains("planets")) {
                objetos.add(Util.getPlanet(url));
            }

            if (url.contains("starships")) {
                objetos.add(Util.getStarship(url));
            }

            if (url.contains("vehicles")) {
                objetos.add(Util.getVehicle(url));
            }

            if (url.contains("species")) {
                objetos.add(Util.getSpecie(url));
            }
        }

        return objetos;
    }
}
```

Util method

```
public static Person getPerson(String characterApiUrl) {

    if (characterApiUrl == null || characterApiUrl.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId(StringUtil.getIdEntity(characterApiUrl, "people/"));
    return person;
}
```

The relationship table is being created but no populated

Comment: What entity are you using saveAll with?

Comment: @K.Nicholas Person and Film, because they are a list, I got all data from the `API`

Comment: Well, for me it either works or gives an unsaved transient expection.